# Editing JComponents on Standard screens

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to customize the JComponents on a built-in Standard Screen?  Specifically, I've been asked to add a Required Disk Space label on the Installation Components screen that updates as different components are selected.  I can get this label to appear by enabling the "Show installation directory chooser" property in the configuration of that screen, but can't figure out a way to prevent the display of the Destination Directory label/text field/button.  `com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.ComponentsScreen` is not an instance of `com.install4j.api.screens.FormPanelContainer` so I'm unable to interact with the FormEnvironment as I might on a custom screen.

Is there a way to either add my own dynamic label to this screen or edit/hide unwanted JComponents that are already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 6.x, there is no was to do that without custom code. I think that the standard screens should just be templates composed of form components, so you can customize them. It's possible that we will do this install4j 7, but right now you would have to derive from

```
com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.ComponentsScreen
```

and override addScreenContent like this:

```
@Override
protected void addScreenContent(JPanel panel, GridBagConstraints gc) {
    super.addScreenContent(panel, gc);
    gc.gridy++;
    panel.add(new JLabel("your label"));
}
```